# Mapping to 2 different functions on a same key binding

Tags: plugins, lua, neovim

I wanted the keymap of ctrl-k to move the cursor to the up position only when there isn't any code completion suggestion from coc.vim , and not work when there is a code completion suggestion, because I use it for moving up in code suggestion given by coc.vim. The same goes to ctrl with j, to move down in suggestion.  What should I write inside the init.lua file or the coc.vim file to achieve this. Because mapping the key to one inhibits the other purpose fo